# Asymptotic Independence of Random Variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables, weak-convergence

Let $(X_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ and $(Y_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ be two sequences of random variables such that the sequences $(X_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ and $(Y_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ converge in law to $X$ and $Y$, where $X$ and $Y$ are also random variable, respectively.

We say then that $X_n$ and $Y_n$ are asymptotically independent if and only if $$P(\{X_n\in A\}\cap\{ Y_n \in B\}) \rightarrow   P(X\in A)P(Y \in B)$$ as $n\to \infty$ for every Borel sets $A$ and $B$.

Is it correct?

Comment: It looks like it could be the definition.  Is there a separate one?

Comment: @herbsteinberg    I have no idea so I had to ask here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not. You need that $P(X_n\in A) \to P(X\in A)$ and $P(Y_n\in B) \to P(Y\in B)$, $n\to\infty$. It is e.g. sufficient that $P(X\in \partial A) = P(Y\in \partial B)=0$.

Comment: You mean that we say that $X_n$ and $Y_n$ are asymptotically independent if and only if $P(\{X_n\in A\}\cap\{ Y_n \in B\}) \rightarrow   P(X\in A)P(Y \in B)$ as $n\to \infty$ for every Borel sets $A$ and $B$ such that $P(X\in \partial A) = P(Y\in \partial B)=0$.

Comment: @Neilhawking, yes, exactly (provided that $X_n\to X$ and $Y_n\to Y$ in law).

Comment: Thanks, Merci, Danke

Comment: @Neilhawking, пожалуйста :)